# composite key on duplicate update -- deletes my rows that feature user id different from the one being inputted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns, and together, they form a composite key. Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `teachers_subjects` (
`subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`users_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `subject_user_id` (`subject_id`,`users_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used to have a third column that was an additional primary key, and on duplicate rows, things worked fine. But that third column didn't really serve any purpose (other than save me from this problem), so I dumped it. This is my PHP function / SQL query:

```
public function update_or_insert_rows($table, $data) {

    # Build the fields string. Ex: (person_id,first_name,email)
    # And the duplicate key update string. Ex: first_name=VALUES(first_name),email=VALUES(email)
    # We do this by using the indexes on the first row of data
    # NOTE: The index of the data array has to start at 0 in order for this to work
        $fields = ""; 
        $dup    = "";
        foreach($data[0] as $index => $value) {
            $fields .= $index.",";
            $dup    .= $index."=VALUES(".$index."),";
        }

        # Remove last comma
        $fields = substr($fields, 0, -1);
        $dup = substr($dup, 0, -1);

    # Build the data string. Ex: (1,'Ethel','ethel@aol.com'),(3,'Leroy','leroy@hotmail.com'),(3,'Francis','francis@gmail.com')
        $values = "";
        foreach($data as $row) {

            $values .= "(";
            foreach($row as $value) {
                $values .= "'".$this->connection->real_escape_string($value)."',";
            }
            $values = substr($values, 0, -1);
            $values .= "),";
        }
        # Remove last comma
        $values = substr($values, 0, -1);

    # Put it all together   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$fields.") 
                VALUES ".$values."
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".$dup;

    # Run it
        $run = $this->query($sql);
        return $this->connection->affected_rows;    
}
```

Now, when I add data to the table, it deletes all rows that feature userids other than the userid of the current user who I'm adding rows with. This makes sense, because in order for my function to work, I need to have a unique third column to whom I include in the data being passed to the table.

I could add that index back in but I was wondering if there was a better solution.

UPDATE: A dumped SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO teachers_subjects (users_user_id,subject_id) VALUES ('98','12') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users_user_id=VALUES(users_user_id),subject_id=VALUES(subject_id)
```

**UPDATE 2:** The problem was not in this SQL query but in a SQL delete from query where I remove rows where boxes that were formerly checked are now unchecked. Still don't know why it's deleting other users rows, but it is somewhere in this code:

```
// delete those subjects that have not been checked
    foreach($_POST['subject_on_page_id'] as $subject_on_page_id) {
        if(!in_array($subject_on_page_id, $_POST['subject_id'])){
            DB::instance(DB_NAME)->delete('teachers_subjects', "WHERE subject_id = ".$subject_on_page_id);
        }
    }
```

This code works by checking the checked boxes against an array built of hidden fields.

Comment: for `$fields` in the query you need to specify all fields in the unique index.  please give a sample query that `$sql` is generating by dumping that value at runtime and add it to question.

Comment: @gillyspy just added SQL query

Comment: that is a very strange `on duplicate key` set of tuples.  They don't handle conflict.  what do you want to have happen when you get a duplicate key?  Perhaps you want `replace into` statement instead?

Comment: @gillyspy on conflict, I'd like to ignore the row, not delete it, as is currently happening

Comment: *This* SQL isn't deleting rows. You're doing that somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple, actually, had nothing to do with my INSERT SQL query. It was my SQL DELETE query, and it merely lacked a second part to the WHERE clause that specified the currently logged in user:

```
&& users_user_id = ".$this->user->user_id
```

I never noticed the problem until after I made a major change to some other, seemingly related part of the site, which I mistakenly attributed the error to. I resolved it after testing out the individual SQL statements individually, that formerly were both executed by a single submit button. Lesson learned! Dump your SQL statements and run them separately to see how things are working!